# Asp.Net OutputCache directive ignored when Substitution control used

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I have a master page that shows the logged in user name. The content page (default.aspx) uses this master and has an OutputCache directive.

The cache works as advertised except for when I add the Substitution control to the master page at which point, all caching stops and I get a fresh page each refresh. The Substitution control inserts the correct username into the page, so it is getting called. But something in there seems to be killing off the cache. The code for returning the user name simply returns a fixed string while I am testing to ensure no side effects.

If I don't use the substitution control the page gets cached, but so does the username which is shown the same to all users).

Is this scenario supported (master page is not cached, Substitution control on master,content page is cached)?

Any troubleshooting hints to see what is invalidating the cache?